# Blit a byte array to screen in SDL

Tags: opengl, graphics, sdl

I am implementing a software rasterizer for school and I would like to simply pass to SDL a buffer with pixels and tell it the format that they are in (RGB, 24b per pixel). SDL would then render that to screen.

I have tried using SDL_Surface but it seems to only work with images or data with headers since the following fails:

```
    unsigned char pixels[BYTES_PER_PIXEL * SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT];
    // ... all pixels are filled with white color

    imageSurface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom(pixels,
      SCREEN_WIDTH,
      SCREEN_HEIGHT,
      sizeof(unsigned char) * BYTES_PER_PIXEL,       // depth
      SCREEN_WIDTH * BYTES_PER_PIXEL,               // pitch (row length * BPP)
      0x000000ff,                                   // red mask
      0x0000ff00,                                   // green mask
      0x00ff0000,                                   // blue mask
      0);                                           // alpha mask
```

The error is: SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom failed: Unknown pixel format.
What is the fastest way to do it in SDL? Also would there be a speed difference between that approach and drawing to an OpenGL texture which I would then render onto a full screen quad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom` `depth` parameter is `the depth of the surface in bits`. `sizeof(unsigned char) * BYTES_PER_PIXEL` is 3 (assuming BYTES_PER_PIXEL is 3, as you said it is 24 bpp) when it should be 24; multiply by number of bits in one byte.

As for the second part - yes there would be. Depends on many things, including CPU and GPU hardware and GL driver. Best way to test is to write both versions. However it is very unlikely you will see big improvement as drawing single quad on screen isn't expensive opearation; other parts of rasteriser should consume significantly more.